# How to check the validity of a string input from GUI in python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, input, alphabet

I'm taking the input for a name in Tkinter, but it's giving an error when I want to check if only alphabets are entered:

```
t1=Label(text="Name:")
t1.place(x=40,y=100)
name=Entry(t)
if name.isalpha():
    print("Valid")
else:
    print("Invalid")
```

How do I check the validity of the input?

Comment: Please include the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check the value of your input field. Use `name.get().isalpha()`.

`name` is just a instance of Entry.
You want the value of this entry field. You can get this by calling `get()` on the Entry instance.

`isalpha()` is defined on `str`ings only.

Comment: You should also mention that they need to wait to call that code until after the user has a chance to enter something. As written, the OP's code will run a millisecond after creating the entry widget.